# Error while calling VSO Rest API from BizTalk WCF-WebHttp Adapter

Tags: biztalk, webhttp, azure-devops-rest-api

I have created a BizTalk application to connect to VSO Rest API to fetch or create work items.

I have configured a wcf-webhttp adapter for calling the rest API.

Before configuring the adapter, I have tested the API with console application and getting the results with same URL.

While running the application I am getting following error:

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SendPort" with URL "the URL". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://xxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/wit/workitems/2 
>   connected host has failed to respond 23.98.150.230:443

But when I paste the URL in the browser I am able to see the result returned by API in the browser.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to trace what is going on?  Or tried enabling WCF tracing?  I see it is on port 443 (SSL), is the certificate self signed?

Comment: It is not self signed, but I was thinking that when it can display the results in browser, how it is different when it is being called from biztalk.

Comment: So try Fiddler or WCF tracing to see what is going on. As Sergio Garcia pointed out in his (non) answer, without more details of your configuration and further details of the problem we can't really help you.  Are you sure that you have configured it to do a GET instead of a POST for example when fetching a work item?  What version of BizTalk are you using?

Comment: I was able to fix this error by using Fiddler. There were some proxy changes required to be made in send port proxy tab. Thanks for help.

Comment: Your welcome,  Fiddler is very useful for working out what is going on.